# Difference between BABYLON.Animation and scene.registerBeforeRender

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I just started to learn more about Babylon.js (I don't know if this is a good choice between p5.js and three.js; throw some suggestions for me).

I came along with this question "which function is used more often between `BABYLON.Animation` and `scene.registerBeforeRender()`. I guess I am more used to use render() method, but I guess Animation function is good when I change the frameRates.

Which is better? which is used more often ?

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas");
const engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);

const createScene =  () => {
    const scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);

    /**** Set camera and light *****/
    const camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("camera", -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2.5, 10, new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
    const light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light", new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 1, 0));

    const box = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateBox("box", {});
    box.position.y = 0.5;
    const ground = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateGround("ground", {width:10, height:10});

    // Animations
    var alpha = 0;
    scene.registerBeforeRender(function () {
        box.rotation.y += 0.05;

    });

    const frameRate = 60;

    const xSlide = new BABYLON.Animation("xSlide", "position.x", frameRate, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONTYPE_FLOAT, BABYLON.Animation.ANIMATIONLOOPMODE_CYCLE);

    const keyFrames = []; 

    keyFrames.push({
        frame: 0,
        value: 2
    });

    keyFrames.push({
        frame: frameRate,
        value: -2
    });

    keyFrames.push({
        frame: 2 * frameRate,
        value: 2
    });

    xSlide.setKeys(keyFrames);

    box.animations.push(xSlide);

    scene.beginAnimation(box, 0, 2 * frameRate, true);

    return scene;
}

const scene = createScene();

engine.runRenderLoop(() => {
    // call render method for our scene
    scene.render();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

scene.registerBeforeRender() is more flexible in changing the values. In your example, you are changing rotation by 0.05 constant value.  In some cases, this may be variable, so you can assign a variable instead of constant value.

It is tricky to change this in Animation class methods, because in KeyFrame, your key and values are fixed once you set them. The only way I could change this is remove animations and add new ones. On a positive side, in Animation class methods, you can change frameRate and change what you want to do in a particular frame.